# Run shellcode in cpp

Tags: c++, function-pointers, shellcode

I am trying to run shellcode in cpp (the shellcode come from the user so the program should be dynamic)
When I try to run my program I got an exception which ,I think, tells me that I can't run code from data section.
after that I tried to create a new exceutable section and put there my data but it didn't work

```
#pragma section(".shell",read,execute)                                                                                                                        
__declspec(allocate(".shell"))
unsigned char code[] =
"\xB8\x04\x00\x00\x00";

// Function pointer points to the address of function.
int(*shell)(); //Function pointer
// Initializing a function pointer  with the address of a shellcode
shell = ((int(*)())&code);
// Execute shellcode
int a = shell();
```

can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the exact symptoms?

Comment: Initializing array of `unsigned char` with an array of `char` is not a good idea.

Comment: this is the exception-
Unhandled exception at 0x0113F005 in ClientSide.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x81D9BAC0.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: That's because of DEP (Data execution prevention). If you really want to execute that shellcode then disabling DEP should allow your shellcode to execute from data section

Comment: yeah but I created a new executable section and stored the data over their (.shell section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you have wrote is correct. Exception is raised just because your shellcode consist only `mov eax, 4`. The Windows allocator aligns your section to the page size and fills it with zeros, but `0x00` is opcode for `add byte ptr [rax], al`. Now you have not only `mov eax, 4` in your shellcode, but:

```
mov eax, 4
add byte ptr [rax],al
add byte ptr [rax],al
....
```

After your `mov` you try to get value at `eax` addres `0x00000004`, where Windows page guard were placed.
And now you have `0xC0000005: Access violation on write "0x0000000000000004"`.

Add `ret` to your shellcode:

```
unsigned char code[] = ""\xB8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xC3"
```

And you won't execute unused commands and exit succesfully.

Comment: @yedidya-kfir, if you have questions, feel free to ask, if this answer is helpful, please mark it as correct answer.